# Filter Outlook AppointmentItem gives strange result

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010

I try to use some kind of range for the `[Start]`:

```
var calendar = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

if (calendar == null || calendar.Items == null)
{
   return null;
}

DateTime appointmentStart = new DateTime(2013, 03, 25, 10, 0 ,0);

string filter = string.Format("[Start] > '{0}' And [Start] < '{1}'", appointmentStart.AddMinutes(-1).ToString("g"), appointmentStart.AddMinutes(+1).ToString("g") );
var calendarItems = calendar.Items.Restrict(filter);
```

And I have an `AppointemtItem` in `Outlook` on `25.03.2013` at `10:00:00`. So am awaiting to get this AppointmentItem as a result of `calendar.Items.Restrict(filter);`

but I become 2 AppointmenItems:

- the correct one
- and also one from 05.04.2012 - from 05 April **2012** (not 2013) which has Start 10:30:00 and End 10:40:00

I cannot understand what have 05.04.2012 10:30:00 - 10:40:00 to do with

filter for > 25.03.2013 09:59 and < 25.03.2013 10:01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Items.IncludeRecurrences` property - [MSDN: IncludeRecurrences Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171434%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `AppointmentItem` from 05.04.2012 is a recurring one.

I dont know why it is shown after `calendar.Items.Restrict(filter)` but the solution for me was to check the `IsRecurring` property.